# Problem using custom PropertyAccessor implementation with annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I've a custom implementation of `PropertyAccessor` that only works if I declare it in the XML mapping file, but not when using field annotations in POJOs).

I try the following:

- With hibernate-core (4.2), XML works but annotation `@AccessType` doesn't.
- With hibernate-core (4.3), XML not tested, annotation `@AttributeAccessor` doesn't work, same problem
- Use `@ColumnTransformer` and `@Formula` instead, but I've not found a formula or a function that suits my needs.

I expect `@AccessType=("my.custom.property.accessor")` or `@AttributeAccessor("my.custom.property.accessor")` to work, but it seems that these annotations or actually their content are ignored.

As a precision, I use field access.

Any help will be really appreciated, I want to move to annotations instead of XML mapping files, and this issue is preventing me to do it.

Thanks in advance.